# Semi-colon after a case valid in a PHP switch statement?

Tags: php, syntax

I'm debugging some code for a client and found the following syntax:

```
switch ($i) {
    case 0;
        echo "i equals 0";
        break;
    case 1;
        echo "i equals 1";
        break;
    case 2;
        echo "i equals 2";
        break;
}
```

The case statements end in semi-colons rather than colons. Turns out this does compile, but is it legit? I've never seen that syntax before.

Comment: @LeviMorrison no, you won't. There's no underlying logic here that can be rationally understood; PHP just arbitrarily allows a semi-colon after a case instead of a colon for some reason. The same syntax is an error in C.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php):

> It's possible to use a semicolon instead of a colon after a case like:
>
> ```
> switch($beer)
> {
>     case 'tuborg';
>     case 'carlsberg';
>     case 'heineken';
>         echo 'Good choice';
>     break;
>     default;
>         echo 'Please make a new selection...';
>     break;
> }
> ```

Answer (score -1):

As you can check here, it works: http://codepad.org/hOLQP98D i think it works because it falls through

Comment: -1; this has nothing to do with fall-through. You're just allowed to use a semicolon instead of a colon after a case, because for whatever reason the PHP devs decided to make it that way.

Answer (score -2):

Yup, just as long as `$i` has a number value

Comment: No, it'll work anyway. `true` = 1; `false` = 0; `"string"` = 0; Only `$i = array('something')` will not print anything. But it will not give any error at all.

Comment: well i should of been a little forward with it, i was implying it can be a string or int value being passed. Sorry for my poor choice of words =)

Comment: It actually works with everything, even `NULL`. With nul or a non set `$i` it will print 0.

Comment: lol, ya your right. in PHP there is more than one way to get a value. null, false, 0, "0" all mean the same thing

Comment: -1; this answer is incorrect (`$i` needn't be a number for this syntax to be illegal) and you've already acknowledged that it's incorrect, so why not delete it?